# Was there a European response to the trail of tears?

Tags: united-states, europe, 19th-century, native-americans, north-america

This question is pretty straightforward. While looking into Victorian British beliefs about Americans and [American history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/46336/what-was-the-victorian-opinion-of-the-american-revolution) I began to wonder about European attitudes toward American Indians; and more specifically their reaction to the human atrocity that was the [Indian Removal Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Removal_Act) and The Trail of Tears. I quickly learned that Tocqueville glimpsed the start of it, and that while he was distressed by the expulsion he wrote it had been done *["tranquilly, legally, philanthropically, without spilling blood, without violating a single one of the great principles of morality in the eyes of the world.”](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2010/05/17/tocqueville-in-america)*

This implies there was no reaction overseas, which is a little hard for me to believe. That's not because I have a high opinion of human nature, but rather because I've observed that competing nations are generally very quick to point out each other's faults. (Just as the British, for example, were quick to criticize the hypocrisy of American slavery, and the Americans were quick to attack British colonialism.) So I thought it might be productive to ask the following here:

**Was there a roughly contemporary European response to the Trail of Tears and the removal of the American Indians?** *Whether in politics, journalism, literature, or elsewhere. As a side note, I'm using the phrase Trail of Tears in the loose sense, as shorthand for the many relocations that took place during the period.*

---

***Update:*** I'm reading Blood Moon by John Sedgwick, and at one point he says that the outside world saw the Trail of Tears as "pitting the Cherokee against Andrew Jackson and his nefarious Indian Removal Act." I haven't had time to finish the book, but a thorough word search makes me think Sedgwick won't elaborate much further. It's an interesting snippet to me because it implies there was an outside reaction, but seems to claim it was the opposite of what Tocqueville thought.

Comment: Remember that in the early 19th century, we had nothing like the global news system that we have now.  It is exceedingly likely that there was general lack of awareness that it was even happening.  When you couple that with the fact that many of the great powers were doing [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_War) things or worse in their colonies, it's unlikely that it would attract much notice.

Comment: @StevenBurnap I think your point about the distance of communication is a very good one (the wonder of the telegraph, let alone a transatlantic cable still being decades away) but still can’t help but suspect it wouldn’t have passed entirely without comment. Europeans were not exactly wanting in moral hypocrisy (or even ignorance of or distaste for their own colonies), and with the often fetishized attention given to American Indians since the enlightenment you’d think there would have at least been a few articles or pamphlets from the left or those inclined to mix politics and Romanticism.

Comment: +1. There must have been some reactions but I did not find them in a few minutes' search.

Comment: Charles Dickens, who generally wrote in favor of the down-trodden English, apparently thought very little of the American Indian: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racism_in_the_work_of_Charles_Dickens#Native_Americans_in_The_Noble_Savage   From this one can conclude that distant peoples were not of much interest to the English, and perhaps to other Europeans either.

Comment: @PeterDiehr Dickens is a hugely influential, and the link is interesting, but having already read a little bit about American Indian envoys who came to Britain from the 1700s to the 1800s I can say with some certainty they were capable of generating intermittent, if not always reliable, bursts of excitement well into the Victorian age. Just the fact that Dickens felt the need to attack the noble savage archetype could be taken as telling.

Comment: @Era Can you clarify what you mean by "European response"? The term "response" being the important descriptive term used in the original question. Are you referring to the individual European (the person; for example, artists, authors; i.e., the common person), or European powers (nation states; monarchies; principalities; ultra-sovereign canon law trusts)?

Comment: This is a worthwhile question but comments so far like generalising from the general attitude of one individual like Dickens or that other countries 'would not care' about distant peoples must be of limited value. Unfortunately I do not know the answer either. If history books and websites say little about it, this could be because an English-speaking historian studying the Trail of Tears naturally concentrates on records in the country where it occurred and may in any case lack language skills to easily check if or how newspapers in Germany or Italy covered it.

Comment: i found hits on books.google.com, limiting the search to 1820-1850 using keywords like, cherokee, choctaw, seminole, creek, chickasaw. British childrens author George Mogridge, paints the Seminole war as a heroic fight against white injustice. Using "cherokee Déportation" i found a somewhat sympathetic French source which translated arguments from the Cherokee's newspaper, the Phoenix. As for my own ancestors of Europe, some of them came to join the Indians in the Territory in the mid 1800s. Interesting question.

Comment: I’ve since found a strong partial answer to this question for Germany specifically— there are several books on the German image of Native Americans on Amazon Preview and Google books and some of them mention German response the trail of tears, which was mixed and ambiguous but largely condemning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Europeans tried to "forestall" the Trail of Tears. That's partly out of sympathy for the Native Americans, but mainly because they were jealous of the resulting accretion of power to the "upstart" Americans.

The French in Canada and "Louisiana" came to trade, rather than colonize, and their missionaries were somewhat successful in converting the Indians to Christianity. They sided with the Native Americans in the French and Indian War, (against the Anglo-Americans), and even though they were allies of America in the Revolution, they were against the Americans being given "East" Louisiana (the land between the Appalachian Mountains and the Mississippi.

After the victory in the French and Indian War, the British passed the [Quebec Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_Act) to prevent "Americans" from encroaching on Native American lands west of the Appalachians in what later became the Northwest Territory. Later, in the War of 1812, the British enlisted the help of Indian leader [Tecumseh,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecumseh) to keep the Americans out of the modern Midwest.

Unlike the Americans, many Europeans were imbued with the idea of the ["noble savage.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_savage) Native Americans were seen as rough and primitive, but not much more so than the white "Americans" who took their places.

Comment: The Quebec Act of 1774 was not meant to contain colonial expansion. It was [a reprisal for the Boston Tea Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intolerable_Acts). You're probably thinking of the [Proclamation of 1763](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Proclamation_of_1763) which created the [Indian Reserve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Reserve_(1763)) that the American colonists objected souch to.

Answer (score -4):

Literary response

- Stein, Gary C. Indian Removal as Seen by European Travelers, *Chronicles of Oklahoma 51* (Winter 1973-1974); 399-410.

  Provides examples of European condemnation of the American policy and the American public's failure to criticize it.
- Stein, Gary C. "And the Strife Never Ends": Indian-White Hostility as Seen by European Travelers in America, 1800-1860, Ethnohistory 20 (Spring 1973) 173-185

  Numerous European travelers to America from 1800-1860observed and discussed the conflicts between Indians and white in the United States. Generally they wrote about the causes of these conflicts within the context pf life in America. Some displayed sympathy for the Indians, others saw him as a hopeless savage, and nearly all predicted his rapid disappearance.

Political and or elsewhere response

The physical European response was for immigrants from Europe to the U.S. to occupy the lands taken from the indigenous peoples by the U.S.

> Large scale immigration resumed in the 1830s from Britain, Ireland,
>   Germany, and other parts of Central Europe as well as Scandinavia.
>   Most were attracted by the cheap farmland.

That "cheap farmland" is the land of the sovereign indigenous nations and peoples which the U.S. took by military force at the same time that the European immigrants were arriving in the U.S.

> Between 1831 and 1840, immigration more than quadrupled to a total of
>   599,000.

Note the correlation between U.S. military actions against the indigenous nations of the U.S. which directly resulted in their property being taken by the U.S. and distributed to European immigrants.

> Between 1841 and 1850, immigration nearly tripled again, totaling
>   1,713,000 immigrants, including at least 781,000 Irish, 435,000
>   Germans, 267,000 British, and 77,000 French.

The vertical expansion of specifically European immigration to the U.S. during the removal of native, indigenous (American Indian) from their sovereign national lands is no coincidence.

The indisputable physical European response that we have on the historical record was the act of vast numbers of Europeans becoming "immigrants" and "settlers" in the lands taken from the indigenous nations in the western hemisphere by U.S. military actions.

Source: [History of immigration to the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_immigration_to_the_United_States#1790_to_1849)

The policy of removing indigenous peoples from their lands by force is not novel to European nation state or principality and subsequent U.S. history, whether that be in the form of direct military aggression, imminent domain, or so-called "race riots".

Note that there are several events in U.S. history which are referred to as the "Trail of Tears".

We can examine the prelude to the conquest of the indigenous nations and peoples in the western hemisphere via several documents composed by European powers before any of the "Trail of Tears" occurred to draw the conclusion that while individual European persons may have objected to the genocide of Native Americans, the policies of the European powers was decidedly [conquest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conquest_(military)).

[Romanus Pontifex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanus_Pontifex)

> ...since we had formerly by other letters of ours granted among other
>   things free and ample faculty to the aforesaid King Alfonso -- to
>   invade, search out, capture, vanquish, and subdue all Saracens and
>   pagans whatsoever, and other enemies of Christ wheresoever placed, and
>   the kingdoms, dukedoms, principalities, dominions, possessions, and
>   all movable and immovable goods whatsoever held and possessed by them
>   and to reduce their persons to perpetual slavery, and to apply and
>   appropriate to himself and his successors the kingdoms, dukedoms,
>   counties, principalities, dominions, possessions, and goods, and to
>   convert them to his and their use and profit -- by having secured the
>   said faculty, the said King Alfonso, or, by his authority, the
>   aforesaid infante, justly and lawfully has acquired and possessed, and
>   doth possess, these islands, lands, harbors, and seas, and they do of
>   right belong and pertain to the said King Alfonso and his successors,
>   nor without special license from King Alfonso and his successors
>   themselves has any other even of the faithful of Christ been entitled
>   hitherto, nor is he by any means now entitled lawfully to meddle
>   therewith.

[Dum diversas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dum_Diversas)

> We grant you [Kings of Spain and Portugal] by these present documents,
>   with our Apostolic Authority, full and free permission to invade,
>   search out, capture, and subjugate the Saracens and pagans and any
>   other unbelievers and enemies of Christ wherever they may be, as well
>   as their kingdoms, duchies, counties, principalities, and other
>   property [...] and to reduce their persons into perpetual servitude.

[Discovery doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_doctrine)

> On the discovery of this immense continent, the great nations of
>   Europe ... as they were all in pursuit of nearly the same object, it
>   was necessary, in order to avoid conflicting settlements, and
>   consequent war with each other, to establish a principle which all
>   should acknowledge as the law by which the right of acquisition, which
>   they all asserted, should be regulated as between themselves. This
>   principle was that discovery gave title to the government by whose
>   subjects, or by whose authority, it was made, against all other
>   European governments, which title might be consummated by possession.
>   ... The history of America, from its discovery to the present day,
>   proves, we think, the universal recognition of these principles.

[Manifest Destiny](http://americanexperience.si.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Manifest-Destiny-and-Indian-Removal.pdf)

> As the boundaries of America grew, white settlers and proponents of
>   expansion began to voice concerns over what they considered an
>   obstacle to settlement and America’s economic and social development –
>   the American Indian tribes living on lands east of the Mississippi
>   River which bordered white settlement. The land was home to many
>   tribal nations including the Cherokee, Creek and Seminole in the south
>   and the Choctaw and Chickasaw in the west. That land held the promise
>   of economic prosperity to raise cattle, wheat, and cotton, and harvest
>   timber and minerals. Eager to take possession of the land, the
>   settlers began to pressure the federal government to acquire the lands
>   from the Indian tribes. To these white settlers, the Indian tribes
>   were standing in the way of progress and of America’s manifest
>   destiny.

[Monroe Doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monroe_Doctrine)

> We owe it, therefore, to candor and to the amicable relations existing
>   between the United States and those powers to declare that we should
>   consider any attempt on their part to extend their system to any
>   portion of this hemisphere as dangerous to our peace and safety. With
>   the existing colonies or dependencies of any European power, we have
>   not interfered and shall not interfere.

[The Debate over Indian Removal in the 1830s](https://scholarworks.umb.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1045&context=masters_theses) (Cass, 17, Kent, Commentaries, Vol. III, 310)

> Cass argued that because Euro-American society was superior to North
>   American Indian society, civilized, Christian, settled agriculturists
>   had a God-given right to redistribute land occupied by barbarian,
>   heathen, wandering hunters. The established customs and practice of
>   colonizing countries from Europe supported Removal and past federal
>   laws and practice supported states such as Georgia in exercising
>   control over Indian communities and disposing of the land they
>   occupied. Cass said that clear Indian title to their land did not
>   really exist, and to support that quoted from arguments made before
>   the US Supreme Court. *(Cass, Lewis. "Considerations of the Present State of the Indians and Their Removal to the West of the Mississippi," North American Review 30 (January 1830) reprint, New
>   York: Arno Press, 1975.) at 20*

> Cass also supported the assertion of Georgia’s right to claim Cherokee
>   land through an entitlement of Christians to take land of
>   non-Christians. He thought it was clear that being a heathen people
>   meant a loss of rights in the face of European claims.

Where the immigrant Europeans response was to *become* American "settler" of lands taken by the U.S. for those same arriving Europeans. The process was a symbiotic relationship. The U.S. is simultaneously stating that European powers where the immigrants were leaving should not interfere in the activities of the U.S. as to any U.S. policy in the western hemisphere.

The European response at that time was mixed, depending on whether the power was Britain or any other European power. Still, the actual people poured in to the U.S. It must be stressed here that the lands that were considered "cheap farmland" is the lands of the original peoples of that land which they were removed from by U.S. military force.

The historical facts are that a vast number of Europeans response was not to protest the removal of the sovereign, indigenous, native american peoples from their lands, but rather, to occupy those lands as "settlers", in effect, becoming instruments of the Indian removal policy themselves.

From the perspective of the native peoples, the entire enterprise of the several states was in effect the policy of Indian removal

John Ross (Kooneskoowe), Cherokee

> ... without the consent or knowledge of the native lords, a potentate of
>   England, whose eyes never saw, whose purse never purchased, and whose
>   sword never conquered the soil we inhabit, presumed to issue a
>   parchment, called a “Charter,” to the colony of Georgia, in which its
>   boundary was set forth, including a great extent of country inhabited
>   by the Cherokee and other Indian Nations.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question as to whether there was a contemporaneous response in Europe to the passage of the Indian Removal Act in 1930 and the twenty-year Trail of Tears forced migrations that followed.

Comment: @jeffronicus What do you mean by "response in Europe"? Europeans had an unambiguous policy towards _all_ native peoples they encountered while they were "discovering" the pre-existing world outside of Europe: _"reduce their persons into perpetual servitude"_. How is 1930 related to the question? One of the many so-called "Trail of Tears" was began in the 1830's, though European powers had long before that time period waged open war against the indigenous populations of the western hemisphere; from Colonial Virginia to Florida, to Mississippi; continuing through to the present day; i.e.; DAPL.

Comment: @jeffronicus Are you seriously expecting the European powers which committed genocide against the native, indigenous peoples and nations of the western hemisphere all of a sudden had some form of conscientious objection to the policies of genocide of the U.S. which their own nations had committed and continued to commit against the native populations of the world? Europe did not have any moral issues with conquest when they used Dum Diversas as a rationale for conquest throughout the known world. Not certain what you are expecting by way of a "response in Europe"? Contest the Monroe Doctrine?

Comment: 1930 was clearly a typo, show a little charity perhaps?

Comment: @Era What exactly are you trying to determine historically? What do you mean by "response"? Technically, the removal of indigenous peoples and nations from their lands has not ceased since Europeans first made contact with indigenous peoples and nations outside of Europe, 1930 being no exception. There has been a continuous policy of genocide against indigenous peoples of the world since at least Dum Diversas, which made the objective of European powers unequivocally clear as to their policies towards all native peoples throughout this world: conquest. What is the relevance of Europe at OP?

Comment: @Era The question is interesting from the perspective of your inclusion of Europe in the title. Though missing is exactly what you mean by "response"; "response" by whom; "response" to what? Removing indigenous peoples from their lands by force is not a novel concept or act from the historical record of European powers. European powers relished in conquest during the 1800's, across the globe; from India to Africa to the western portion of Turtle Island. If you are focused on the individual "response", that is, in literature, that distinction should be made clear.

Comment: @Era The [Monroe Doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monroe_Doctrine) made it clear that the U.S. would view European colonization or expansion in influence in north or south America as potentially an act of war against the U.S. A European power would necessarily be aware that attempting to interfere with removal of indigenous peoples in the U.S. would mean war. For the individual person, indigenous peoples of Turtle Island have long exchanged medicine with the entire world, as evidenced by the various regalia found on Turtle Island and across the globe. See also "The West" by Ken Burns.

Comment: @jeffronicus The physical response was for European immigrants to move into the lands taken from the indigenous peoples by the U.S. _"Large scale immigration resumed in the 1830s from Britain, Ireland, Germany, and other parts of Central Europe as well as Scandinavia. Most were attracted by the cheap farmland."_, _"Between 1831 and 1840, immigration more than quadrupled to a total of 599,000."_, _"Between 1841 and 1850, immigration nearly tripled again, totaling 1,713,000 immigrants, including at least 781,000 Irish, 435,000 Germans, 267,000 British, and 77,000 French."_

Comment: @Era See updated post. The overwhelming European response was to get on a boat, immigrate to the U.S., and become "settlers" occupying the land that was taken militarily by the U.S. during one of the many so-called "Trail of Tears" or "Long Walk", becoming instruments of the removal policy of the U.S. If Europeans would have objected en masse to the Indian removal policies they would have simply stayed in Europe.

Comment: @Era You might be able to locate some objections to the removal policies in literary form documented in the series "The West" by Ken Burns. You might also look into the purpose of the so-called "Gold Rush", which was an invention to motivate those European immigrants to traverse from east to west, in order to extend the boundaries of the U.S. from coast to coast; there was little if any "gold in them there hills".

Comment: This answer is fundamentally correct. Perhaps a better take would be "Most Europeans were unaware of the plight of Native Americans, as they were dealing with horrible social issues of their own."

Comment: @axsvl77 Are you implying that a) most Europeans in the 1830's were not aware that Native Americans existed; that b) most Europeans were unaware that the advertised "cheap farm land" was in fact the land of the sovereign peoples and nations which the U.S. had the official policy of taking by military force; or that c) the conditions for most Europeans in Europe were bleak enough that wherever they wound up, and whether or not them winding up there geographically included displacing the native population, it would be better for them than Europe at the time?

Comment: @axsvl77 Is your point that most Europeans during the 1830's were illiterate? If they did not immigrate to the U.S. they were unaware of the Indians in the first instance; or If they did immigrate to the U.S. they were indoctrinated to their role as "settler" upon arrival at their "cheap farm land" in person (or any other location acquired by military force by the U.S.) without the necessity of being literate to understand their role as "settler" on lands where Indians had been "removed" (cannot object and return to Europe now, still better than being in Europe)?

Comment: @guest271314 Good question. I'm implying that the people who displaced the Native Americans were mostly akin to refugees. Fleeing death by economics and war, those who made it to the US as settlers were very hard people.

Comment: I believe some of my ancestors fled the absorption of Poland by Russia in the 1830s, and were involved in farming in the Upper Peninsula. Others fled genocide under Ottoman rule. I really doubt 1830 peasant farmers in Poland would have any awareness of the problems face by North American native peoples. It is akin to how nobody seems to know or care about a million [Rohingya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rohingya_persecution_in_Myanmar) being persecuted today.

Comment: (This stuff makes me very sad.)

Comment: It seems the author simply used this question as an excuse to write a diatribe he had been storing up.  It simply does not address the question at all.

Comment: @pokep There is no need for "storing up" information relevant to the policies of U.S. towards the indigenous populations of the western hemisphere. Western academia has written extensively about their exploits of conquest themselves. The information was available before this question was asked. The answer is the response by Europeans is the physical evidence of immigration from Europe to the U.S. (for various reasons) rising exponentially directly proportional to occupation of those Europeans on lands where the U.S. had removed the sovereign nations of Indians by military force.

Comment: Perhaps you could present actual reactions to the specific event in contemporary European sources (such as newspapers and pamphlets), such as the question actually asks for?

Comment: @pokep What do you mean by "reactions"? Are you expecting sympathetic, romantic or shocked views from Europe proper literature as to the Indian wars of America as described by Europeans whom were engaged in their own local wars, which prompted the people to leave Europe in the first instance? Not sure what specific type of documentation you are searching for. For many, apparently ignorance of the environment to be faced in the U.S. upon arrival was still better than the expectations in Europe. What could newspapers possible state that the population which was leaving in large numbers believe?

Comment: @pokep If they were literate at all, the petty bourgeoisie and peasants were far too busy with the [Revolutions of 1830](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutions_of_1830) to write about the Indian Removal Act in U.S. Though if you are able to locate such literature, will include it in the answer. The data is not being excluded from the answer on purpose. Europe was in tumult and roving reporters who could shuttle between continents and conflicts on jets did not exist at that time.

Comment: @guest271314   Obviously all those petty bourgeoisie were too busy to read the roughly 50 newspapers being published in London alone at the time, let alone the hundreds of others.  A single reference from any of those, or the hundreds of other published elsewhere on the Isles and the Continent would have been appropriate, since that is what the questioner clearly wanted to know about.

Comment: @pokep Read the question literally here _"Was there a roughly contemporary European response to the Trail of Tears and the removal of the American Indians? Whether in politics, journalism, literature, or elsewhere."_ the or elsewhere being the physical evidence of Europeans immigrating to lands where they became ["settlements of whites"](https://memory.loc.gov/cgi-bin/ampage?collId=llrd&fileName=010/llrd010.db&recNum=438). If not a single word was written about the topic in European media the effect is that "elsewhere" sovereign nations were being removed from their lands by and for Europeans.

Comment: @guest271314  But you don't even attempt to show that "not a single word was written".

Comment: @pokep We have little proof that words were written on the matter in Europe. Europe had numerous domestic conflicts and issues ongoing at the time. The Rothschilds were probably aware of the matter. A "response" in specifically literature or popular media is not a simple matter to locate. Have located some advertisements for "emigration" to the U.S. from Liverpool. If you have primary resources as to popular media or literature addressing the Indian Removal Act of 1830, you should post an answer. This answer primarily addresses the "politics" and "or elsewhere" portion of the inquiry.

Comment: @pokep As to literature OP is probably looking for _Indian Removal as Seen by European Travelers in America_ by Gary C. Stein (Chronicles of Oklahoma, 51 at pg. 399)

Comment: @pokep Included citation to the relevant literature at the answer.