# What's a major 19th Century history of the American Revolution from a British perspective?

Tags: 19th-century, united-kingdom, american-revolution

I recently read McCaulay's History of England, which he initially projected to cover in detail events up to the reign of Queen Victoria.  I was excited to see his take on the American revolution, particularly in light of his highly detailed recounting of Parliamentary interplay and court politics.  However, McCaulay only lived long enough to complete his work through the final years of William of Orange.

Undaunted, I picked up Dickens' Child's History of England, hoping by the end to get at least a taste of the 19th Century British perspective on the American Revolution.  However, flipping ahead, I found that Dickens will be cutting out at around the same point.

Is there a history which covers the American Revolution, written by a (relatively) high-profile 19th Century British author, preferably on the order of a Dickens, McCaulay, or Carlyle?

Comment: The "Related" sidebar on the right is a wonderful thing :)
Have a look at [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/46336/what-was-the-victorian-opinion-of-the-american-revolution) which deals with the subject.